# Python - Print line based on partial string

Tags: python, file, compare, output, string-matching

I have 2 files that I am wanting to check against each other and pull out the line that they are contained in.

I was trying to do it with regex but I keep getting this error, presuming it's because I'm reaching into a file rather than just presenting a string directly

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\re.py", line 248, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

This is what I'm using for the regex search

```
regex = r"\d(.*(10.0.0.0).*)"

with open('test1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    test = file1.read().splitlines()
    matches = re.finditer(regex, test)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
```

I have also tried this, but still comes up with an error

```
with open("test1.txt") as file1, open("test2") as file2:
    st = set(map(str.rstrip,file1))
    for line in file2:
        spl = line.split(None, 1)[0]
        if spl in st:
            print(line.rstrip())
```

The error is

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to match a list of IPs to the output from a router, so the test2 file will look like this

```
10.0.0.0/8
11.0.0.0/8
12.0.0.0/8
13.0.0.0/8
```

With the router output looking like

```
1 X test         10.0.0.0/8                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
2 X test         11.0.0.0/8                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
3 X test         12.0.0.0/8                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
4 X test         13.0.0.0/8                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
```

I am wanting the entire line from the router to be matched just with the IP rather than having to put the entire expected output

Hope this is enough to go off, still pretty new to all this, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer is

```
with open("router_output.txt") as file1, open("list_of_ips.txt") as file2:
    ips_to_keep = file2.read().splitlines()
    router_lines = file1.read().splitlines()

ips_to_keep = [" " + ip + " " for ip in ips_to_keep]

for line in router_lines:
    if any(ip in line for ip in ips_to_keep):
        print(line)
```

assuming that your file has spaces and not tabs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file with the actual IPs, and you don't need regexes, then you can do something like this

```
my_str = """
1 X test         10.0.0.0/8                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
2 X test         11.0.0.0/9                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
3 X test         12.0.0.0/12                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
4 X test         13.0.0.0/2                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08
5 X test         555.0.0.0/2                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08 #expecting this to not be printed
"""

keep_ips = [' 10.0.0.0/8 ', ' 11.0.0.0/9 ', ' 12.0.0.0/12 ', ' 13.0.0.0/2 ']


for line in my_str.split('\n'):
    if any(ip in line for ip in keep_ips):
        print(line)
```

I added the padding of spaces in the `keep_ips` because otherwise you could match on something like `113.0.0.0/25`, because it contains the substring `13.0.0.0/2`

You could refactor this code to read in the lines from the router, then the lines for the IPs, add spaces to either end of the IPs, then use this logic, using `any`

I hope this works for you now

Comment: Your issue is that `regex = r"\d(.*(10.0.0.0).*)"` only matches things which has `10.0.0.0` in it, which is very restrictive. If you want to match stuff like `172.12.3.215/24`, then you're going to have to be smarter with your regex, and read into how to match a different number of possible numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Unfortunately, this isn't what I was looking for, I am wanting to keep the IPs in a separate file from the script and the router output. The IPs I used in this were also an example and I would be using different IPs that wouldn't match this regex (unless there is a way to import strings in a regex argument from a file). 
Also needs to get the full line as I need the rule ID the router has assigned so that I can automate actions (ID is the no. on the left of the router output).
If you need extra info or the full script lmk

Comment: So, you want to basically filter the file which has lines

`1 X test         10.0.0.0/8                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08`

so only lines with IPs from `test2`  file are there? Still a bit confused

Comment: So you would create a list of IPs in a file, and then compare those IPs to the output from the router. If any match, print the full line that has come from the router.
So if you're checking for 10.0.0.0 it would print the full 
`1 X test         10.0.0.0/8                          nov/19/2021 13:03:08`